# MS SQL Как объединить таблицы без условия?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть xml с Id  и таблица Client, нужно сделать выборку данных: Id.id, Client.Name, каждому id должно соответствовать только одно Name.
Текущее решение заключается в создание 2-х временных таблиц, в которых есть поле [Id_num] INT IDENTITY(1, 1), по которому затем и происходит объединение, есть ли другие способы решить проблему?

```
-- Предусловие 
CREATE TABLE #Client (Name nvarchar (10))

INSERT INTO #Client VALUES('Alisa')
INSERT INTO #Client VALUES('Bob')
INSERT INTO #Client VALUES('Eva')

-- Запрос
DECLARE @Ids [nvarchar](MAX) = N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfLong xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <long>1</long>
  <long>2</long>
  <long>3</long>
</ArrayOfLong>'

DECLARE @DocHandle INT
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @Ids

CREATE TABLE #Ids (
      Id_num INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
      ,Id BIGINT
    )

INSERT INTO #Ids (Id)
SELECT id
FROM OPENXML(@DocHandle, '/ArrayOfLong/long', 8) WITH (id BIGINT '.')

CREATE TABLE #TempClients (
      Id_num INT IDENTITY(1, 1)
      ,Name nvarchar (10)
    )

INSERT INTO #TempClients (Name) SELECT Name FROM #Client

SELECT [Id], [Name]
FROM #Ids AS id
JOIN #TempClients AS client ON client.Id_num = id.Id_num

DROP TABLE #Client
DROP TABLE #Ids
DROP TABLE #TempClients
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @DocHandle
```

Comment: Есть, но они все извращённые, поскольку задача не сильно ложится на реляционную алгебру. Попробуйте вместо создания временных таблиц добавить в выборку `ROW_NUMBER()`, и затем сделать `INNER JOIN` по этому полю.

Comment: Если в Client нет ID, по которому можно их сопоставить с ID из xml, то это не надёжно.

Comment: Надежность тут и не нужна, нужно распределить id по клиентам, а кому какой достанется, значения не имеет, главное чтобы у двух клиентов не было одинакового id.

Comment: Тогда в принципе верно, но можно короче.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно не создавать столько временных таблиц (в крайнем случае я бы создал одну, чтобы прочитать в неё id из xml, т.к. join на методы xml типа не всегда быстр).

Наши данные:

```
declare @client table (name nvarchar (10))
insert into @Client values
    ('Alisa'), ('Bob'), ('Eva')

declare @ids xml =
'<idlist>
  <long>3</long>
  <long>11</long>
  <long>17</long>
</idlist>'
```

Запрос:

```
;with
id as (
    select
        rn = row_number() over (order by t.c),
        id = t.c.value('text()[1]', 'int')
    from @ids.nodes('/*[1]/long') t(c)
),
cl as (
    select
        rn = row_number() over (order by name),
        name
    from @client
)
select id.id, cl.name
from id
    join cl on cl.rn = id.rn
```

Т.е. нумеруем все id, и нумеруем всех клиентов, а потом сопоставляем их по номеру.

Если id идут по порядку, то xml вообще кажется лишним, ведь можно раздать id и проще:

```
select
    id = row_number() over (order by name),
    name
from @client
```